# Spring Boot test entity field validation with custom validation

Tags: spring-boot, validation, entity

Setup:

- Spring Boot 2.3.3 (spring-boot-starter-validation)
- JUnit 5 Jupiter
- Lombok

Entity fields can be annotated with simple `javax.validation` constraints like `@Positive`.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    @Positive(message="not positive")
    private int age;
}
```

This can be tested quite easily:

```
public class PersonTest {

    private Validator validator;

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void invalid_becauseNegativeAge() {
        Person uut = Person.builder().age(-1).build();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> actual = validator.validate(uut);
        assertThat(actual.iterator().next().getMessage()).isEqualTo("not positive");
    }
}
```

Now I add a custom validator to `Person`:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    @Positive(message="not old enough")
    private int age;

    @ComplexValueConstraint
    private String complexValue;
}
```

Custom annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ComplexValueValidator.class)
public @interface ComplexValueConstraint {

    String message() default "too simple";    
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};    
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Custom validator:

```
class ComplexValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ComplexValueConstraint, Person> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Person person, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    String complexValue = person.getComplexValue();
    if (complexValue.length() < 5) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Now, my test from above fails with a

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'ComplexValueConstraint' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'complexValue'
```

How can I make this test to work again? I know I could test the validator in isolation, but then my simple annotations like `@Positive` would remain untested.

Is it because I create the validator in the test class manually? @Autowired won't work somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring that `ComplexValueValidator` validates objects of type `Person`:

```
ComplexValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ComplexValueConstraint, Person>
```

but the annotation is applied to a field of type `String` instead of a field of type `Person`:

```
@ComplexValueConstraint
private String complexValue;
```

Hence the message that the constraint can not be applied to a `java.lang.String`.

Try changing `complexValue` to be of type `Person` instead of type `String`.